# Update SystemTray ProgressIndicator Value from Asynchronous Method

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, async-await

I have a long-running background operation to synchronize user data with a remote web service and would like to give the user feedback on the status of that operation. The SystemTray ProgressIndicator is bound in XAML to properties on the ViewModel like so:

```
<shell:SystemTray.ProgressIndicator>
    <shell:ProgressIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsSynchronizing, Mode=OneWay}"
                             Text="Synchronizing..."
                             Value="{Binding SyncProgress, Mode=OneWay}" />
</shell:SystemTray.ProgressIndicator>
```

The bindings here work correctly at the outset of the call. My async web service operation is invoked from the ViewModel, and I provide it with a callback to set the values of its properties based on the current status of the operation:

```
RemoteServiceManager.Current.UpdateUserDataAsync((progress) =>
{
    // Marshal to UI thread
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        IsSynchronizing = !progress.OperationFinished;
        SyncProgress = progress.PercentComplete;

        if (progress.OperationFinished)
        {
            OnDataChanged();
        }
    });
});
```

The problem with this approach is that the UI dispatcher never seems to invoke the action (setters never get called), and if I remove the call to the dispatcher and execute the code inside the delegate directly, the code will execute without generating exceptions but the bound properties on the progress indicator won't update with the new progress value. How do I update the ProgressInidcator Value property properly from this long-running async operation?

Another brief final question: Should the Value I set on the ProgressIndicator range from 0-1 or 0-100?

Comment: `The problem with this approach is that the UI dispatcher never seems to invoke the action` If the dispatcher really never calls your action, it means you're doing some long-running processing on the UI thread. That something you should avoid at all cost

Comment: @KooKiz My web service client is generated with async calls and I've wrapped every one of them to conform to the async/await pattern. The web service interaction is not happening on the UI thread. The UI is quite responsive. The moment I hit the first await keyword in UpdateUserDataAsync, I'm relatively sure the result is handled on a separate thread. The ViewModel isn't awaiting any results either.

Comment: Weird, if the UI is responsive then I see no reason why the dispatcher wouldn't call your action. Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the `IsSynchronizing = !progress.OperationFinished;` line?

Comment: @KooKiz I did. Never seems to get hit. I'm really baffled. I'll try wrapping it in an action to the task factory and see what happens.

Comment: @KooKiz It looks like wrapping the call in an action and passing it to the Task factory resolved the problem. Your instincts were correct. I probably need to look more closely at the behavior of async/await because I'm under some false assumptions about what happens. If you wouldn't mind writing it up I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the only case when the dispatcher won't call your action is when the UI thread is already busy.

When calling an async method, the current synchronization context is captured. When the async call is done, the code after your `await` statement is executed on the captured synchronization context. The synchronization context is, for instance, the UI thread. It's therefore important to remember that, if you were in the UI thread before a call to `await`, you'll still be in that UI thread when the call is done.

Also, it's a common mistake to think of a task as a thread. A task is just an unit of work. It does not execute necessarily in a separate thread. In fact, if you write an async method but never start a new thread, then your method will execute in the current thread. Why is it done like that? Simply because you don't always need a thread to be asynchronous. If, for instance, you're just subscribing to an I/O event, creating a thread would be a waste of resources.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating an `IProgress<T>` object

```
IProgress<ProgressInfo> progressIndicator = new Progress<ProgressInfo>(ReportProgress);
```

and passing this into your `async` method

```
public async void YourMethodAsync(IProgress<ProgressInfo> progressIndicator)
{
    ProgressInfo pi = new ProgressInfo(0);
    ...
    // Report progress.
    pi.PrecentageComplete = 30;
    progressIndicator.Report(pi);
    ...
}
```

where

```
public class ProgressInfo 
{
    private int progressPercentage;

    public ProgressInfo() {}

    public ProgressInfo(int progressPercentage)
    {
        this.progressPercentage = progressPercentage;
    }

    public int ProgressPercentage
    {
        get { return progressPercentage; }
        set { progressPercentage = value; }
    }
}
```

and the `ReportProgress` method is something like

```
public void ReportProgress(CostEngine.ProgressInfo progressInfo) 
{
    SyncProgress = progressInfo.PercentComplete;
}
```

which will be invoked on the UI thread automatically.

I hope this helps.